Finding the vertices of the hyperbola $x^2+6xy-7y^2=20$
Given the hyperbola
$$x^2+6xy-7y^2=20$$ how do I find its vertices?
I have found its asymptotes by factoring it into $$(x+7y)(x-y)=20$$ to obtain its asymptotes: $$y=x$$ and $$y=-\frac{1}{7}x.$$ I do not know what to do next to find the vertices. I have searched the internet but, infuriatingly, I have not been able to answer this question. I do not wish to use trigonometry, linear algebra, or calculus, only geometry, as the problem I am working on hints at using angle bisectors and symmetry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Vertices lie on one of the angle bisectors of the asymptotes, so you just need to find what lines those are and compute intersections. (Also, please watch out, the algebraic geometry tag is not for this sort of question - per the tag description, "[t]his tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry.")

The conic is central, so the vertices are at least distance from center i.e. origin
With $x=r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ we get $r^2 = \dfrac{20}{3 \sin 2 \theta + 4 \cos 2 \theta -3} \ge \dfrac{20}{5-3} = 10$ when $ \cos 2 \theta = \dfrac{4}{5}$ and $\sin 2 \theta = \dfrac{3}{5}$
Hence the vertices will be $(3,1)$ and $(-3,-1)$
